# How to update recyclerview adapter for the changed data after Volley call

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

In the app that I'm developing, there is an API which gets called repeatedly to show data in a recyclerview. Each time the server returns the same set of data until the  `task_status` is 'finished'. It is important that I keep refreshing the displayed cards if there is a change in any of the fields. Additionally, it shall add new cards if a new set of data is added. The problem right now is, a new set of cards are added each time when the API gets called even though there is no change in any fields or no new set of data.

**JSON Array**

```
[
{
    p_id: "011",
    m_status: "deliveryon",
    p_name: "Alfred Kusher",
    p_position: "Delivery Optimiser",
    p_location: "Vancuver"
},
{
    p_id: "021",
    m_status: "intask",
    p_name: "Wilson Divachik",
    p_position: "Driver",
    p_location: "Ontario"
},
{
    p_id: "014",
    task_status: "enroute",
    p_name: "Dalvin Petter",
    p_position: "Driver",
    p_location: "Lunenbrg"
},
{
    p_id: "244",
    task_status: "intask",
    p_name: "Maria Laoumi",
    p_position: "Assistant Marketing Manager",
    p_location: "Ottawa"
},
{
    p_id: "004",
    task_status: "active",
    p_name: "Linda Jefferson",
    p_position: "Sales Lead",
    p_location: "Quebec"
},
{
    p_id: "055",
    task_status: "active",
    p_name: "Dimitar Kurmanov",
    p_position: "Senior Manager",
    p_location: "Nova Scotia"
}
]
```

For example, according to the sample JSON response above it should add 6 cards at the first time when the API gets called and only make changes to the displayed data if there are any changes to any fields ( like `p_location` or `task_status`) in the subsequent calls. Furthermore, add a new card if there is a new set of data.

**APICall.Java**

```
 public void PERSON_DATA_WEB_CALL() {

    String HTTP_SERVER_URL = String.format("http://myURL.com/%1$s", LoginID);

    JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, HTTP_SERVER_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    PERSON_DATA_PROCESSING(response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            }) {

    };
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsArrRequest);
}


public void PERSON_DATA_PROCESSING(JSONArray array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        PersonDataModel GetPerDataModel = new PersonDataModel();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            GetPerDataModel.setID(json.getString("p_id"));
            GetPerDataModel.setTaskStatus(json.getString("task_status"));
            GetPerDataModel.setName(json.getString("p_name"));
            GetPerDataModel.setPosition(json.getString("p_position"));
            GetPerDataModel.setLoction(json.getString("p_location"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        PersonDataAdapterClassList.add(GetPerDataModel);

    }

    if (array.length() != 0) {
        recyclerViewAdapter = new PersonRecyclerAdapter(PersonDataAdapterClassList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    } 

}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class PersonRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
public List<PersonDataModel> dataModels;
private static int currentPosition = 0;
public PersonRecyclerAdapter(List<PersonDataModel> getDataAdapter, Context context) {
    super();
    this.dataModels = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}
public PersonDataModel dataAdapter;

@Override
public PersonRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.person, parent, false);
    PersonRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new PersonRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    dataAdapter = dataModels.get(position);
    viewHolder.id.setText(dataAdapter.getID());
    viewHolder.location.setText(dataAdapter.getLocation());
    viewHolder.taskStatus.setText(dataAdapter.getMStatus());
    viewHolder.name.setText(dataAdapter.getName());
    viewHolder.p_position.setText(dataAdapter.getPPosition());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return dataModels.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView id;
    public TextView taskStatus;
    public TextView location;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView p_position;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPID);
        taskStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTaskStatus);
        location = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLocation);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        p_position = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPosition);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
PersonDataAdapterClassList.add(GetPerDataModel);
```

You are actually appending the whole response at the end of the list.

Instead, you should change the way you store the data, maybe a map with p_id as key, and then update or create when parsing the response.

Another thing that you can do, easier, but maybe less efficient: you can wipe the whole list before processing the response:

```
public void PERSON_DATA_PROCESSING(JSONArray array) {
    PersonDataAdapterClassList.clear();
    for (...
```

By doing that at the beginning it should work and you can keep the rest of your current code. Nevertheless, it sounds a fair use case for a map.

One more question, if one element stopped showing in a subsequent request should it be removed? If yes, clearing the data is the right approach, if you need to preserve it, then use the map.

One more tip, instead of resetting the adapter everytime you can notify the updates to the adapter. By resetting the adapter the recyclerview could recreate all the views.

For this, you should change the code of your adapter:

```
public class PersonRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context; 
    private final List<PersonDataModel> dataModels;
    private static int currentPosition = 0;

    public PersonRecyclerAdapter(Context context) { 
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.dataModels = new ArrayList<PersonDataModel>();
    }

    public void updateModels(List<PersonDataModel> newModels) {
        dataModels.clear();
        dataModels.adAll(newModels);
        notifyDataSetChaged();
    }
    ...
```

Now, when you create the recyclerview, you should create the adapter there, and keep a reference to it

```
recyclerview = findViewById...
recyclerViewAdapter = new PersonRecyclerAdapter(this);
recyclerview.setAdaper(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

then in your api call:

```
public void PERSON_DATA_PROCESSING(JSONArray array) {
    List<PersonDataModel> newModels = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        PersonDataModel GetPerDataModel = new PersonDataModel();
        JSONObject json = null; 
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            GetPerDataModel.setID(json.getString("p_id"));
            GetPerDataModel.setTaskStatus(json.getString("task_status"));
            GetPerDataModel.setName(json.getString("p_name"));
            GetPerDataModel.setPosition(json.getString("p_position"));
            GetPerDataModel.setLoction(json.getString("p_location"));

            newModels.add(GetPerDataModel);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }

    if (array.length() != 0) { 
        recyclerViewAdapter.updateModels(newModels);
    } 
}
```

Comment: In my case, it won't stop showing, it just changes the value. Could you please explain the solution in my code. I'm new to this one actually. Thanks

Comment: PersonDataAdapterClassList is the list that holds all the data, I presume. The add method that you use to add each item from the response appends the item to the end of the list. The list will keep everything. So the second request, the list will have the results of the previous request, when you do add, you add the items again. When you pass the list it will have the items for the first response and those for the second. The clear I suggested removes everything from the list, so you can add them again. Try adding the clear and see if it works.

Comment: I have added `PersonDataAdapterClassList.clear()` as you have mentioned. Now it does not add additional cards apart from the initial 6. But the issue now is it does scroll back to the first card each time the api gets called.

Comment: It scrolls back because you are resetting the adapter everytime. You should keep a reference of the adapter and call notifyDataSetChaged (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged() ) on the adapter instead of creating a new one. If the data don't changed, maybe it didn't changed in the server?

Comment: I just saw your edit and was implementing the changes you have suggested, it is showing Cannot resolve method `'updateModels(java.util.List<com.example.administrator.PersonDataModel>)'`

Comment: Declare recyclerViewAdapter as PersonReciclerAdapter